# CSS layout: tabs leaving right space

Tags: css

I have a page designed for tabbed browsing. The tabs are `<li>`s, which are displayed as blocks. The parent div of tabs is set to float right. But the last tab is leaving some space with right. It is not getting attached to the right side portion of window. I want the tab (or the tabs parent) to attach to the right side or it may leave a 1px space.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/pfzXP/)** is the fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
#menu {
    float: right;
    height: 34px;
    width: 590px;
}
```

into

```
#menu {
    float: right;
    height: 34px;
}
```

All you need is to delete width of parent div, and all will be OK)))

Answer (score 0):

Your parent div of tabs is floated right, but your `<ul>` inside is not.  With a set width on #menu, unless your `<li>`s take up the full width there will always be space on the right.

You can either remove the width attribute of #menu, or add

```
float:right;
```

to #menu ul{}